# Как правильно: пополоскали или прополоскали?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мы платочки постирали,
А потом пополоскали *(или прополоскали?)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и так и так.
Пополоскали - какое-то время послоскали.
Прополоскали - сделали, добились результата.

Answer (score 1):

Пополоскали-то пополоскали, а вот выполоскали ли? А уж если прополоскали, так это точно выполоскали! (Приставка про- придает глаголу значение полной законченности действия, приставка по - неполной меры действия.)

Answer (score 0):

прополоскали будет  правильно,иначе никак